# REGEXP to Match a list of words containing + and spaces

Tags: mysql

I need to create a query that looks for a exact match for a list of words like '+lg +customer +service' (this is one word and needs to be the exact match) unfortunately I cannot use a WHERE IN ('+lg +customer +service','+Phone +repairs'). Cannot use this because the app cannot build the list of values because it's over 36K, but I can use a REGEXP if I could get it right...

I tried to to use it like that:

```
WHERE Text REGEXP '/[\+Phone\ \+repairs]/|/[\+lg\ \+customer\ \+service]/'
```

This doesn't work though, returns no result as soon as I add this.

Anyone knows how REGEXP works for exact phrase match?

Comment: Which/What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Why has the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax) not been able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Referring the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax), for an EXACT Match you could go for this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where
    content REGEXP '\\+lg \\+customer \\+service';
```

or multiple exact matches like

```
SELECT * FROM test.new_table where 
    content REGEXP '\\+lg \\+customer \\+service$,' or content REGEXP '\\+Phone \\+repairs$';
```

Checked using **Mysql Workbench 6.3, Mysql 5.6 version**

Comment: Thanks @Monster Brain! Doesn't really work for what I'm trying to do. 

Basically there are multiple strings that contain '\\hotpoint \\customer \\service', like hotpoint customer service uk, contact hotpoint customer service, so there are multiple exact matches to this string. I have searched quite a lot today but doesn't seen to exist a way around it, just if I use the Where clause IN ('value1','value2').

Thank you very much though!

Comment: Where clause IN ('value1','value2') unfortunately cannot be used as the application doesn't support typing and the list of values doesn't render on the app because it has 36k+ values.

Thank you very much though!

Comment: Oh Ok. maybe try this also for multiple matches, content REGEXP '\\+[:alpha:]*';